# Why is the value of only this variable ignored when constructing an object with {}?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, constructor

I have an APIRequest class on which I need a default value for the isInBackground variable.

APIRequest class simplified :

```
public class APIRequest
{
    public string url;
    public bool isInBackground = true;
}
```

When I do this, the value of isInBackground is always ignored and set to the default :

```
APIRequest rq = new APIRequest{
        url = "/user/suggest/" + pseudo,
        isInBackground = false
};
```

Then I log the value and get 'True', however url is the right value...

The only way to set it to 'False' is to do

```
rq.isInBackground = false;
```

Then the value is indeed 'False'

So my question is why does it behave this way ? Is it because isInBackground has a default value ?

```
public class APITest {
    public string url;
    public bool background = true;
}

public class TestClass : MonoBehaviour {

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {
       APITest t = new APITest{
          url = "coucou",
          background = false
      };

      Debug.Log(" url: " + t.url + " background: " + t.background);
  }
}
```

Edit : After trying to set the default value to 'False' and set the variable to 'True' the problem doesn't occur...

Edit to show full code :

```
private void ShowPseudoSuggestionsFor(string pseudo){
    Debug.Log("Get suggestions");
    RemoteRequest r = RemoteRequest.GetNewRequest("PseudoSuggestions");
    APIRequest rq = new APIRequest{
        url = "/user/suggest/" + pseudo,
        successCallback = OnSuggestionsLoaded,
        successCallbackArgs = new Hashtable{
            { "pseudo", pseudo }
        },
        isInBackground = false
    };
    //rq.isInBackground = false;
    Debug.Log("isInBackground : " + rq.isInBackground);
    r.SetRequest(rq);
    Debug.Log("isInBackground : " + rq.isInBackground);
    r.SendRequest();
}
```

Full APIRequest class :

```
public class APIRequest
{
    public string url;                                          /*!< Url you wish to send you request at */
    public HTTPMethod method = HTTPMethod.GET;                                  /*!< HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) */
    public Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();                   /*!< Headers, add one with headers.Add(<headerName>, <headerValue>) */
    public byte[] payload;                                      /*!< If you need to send POST or PUT data create a WWWForm, add the fields you need in it and then set payload to be <yourForm>.data */

    public bool resendOnFailure = false;                        /*!< Should we resend the request if it fails ? */
    public bool resendOnTimeout = false;                        /*!< Should we resend the request if it times out ? */ 
    public bool isInBackground = true;                          /*!< Should we send request start and completed events */
    public bool askBeforeResending = false;                     /*!< Should we ask user before resending request ? */
    public Rect askingPopupRect;                                /*!< Size of the popup that will ask user to resend request */
    public string askingPopupTitle;                             /*!< Title for resend request popup */
    public string askingPopupMessage;                           /*!< Message for resend request popup */
    public GUI.WindowFunction drawAskingPopup;                  /*!< Function responsible for drawing the resend request popup */

    public float timeout = 10f;                                     /*!< Time until the request is considered a failure */
    public int maxAttempts = 1;                                 /*!< Maximum number of attempts before which request will be resent, upon reaching it, no more attempts to resend will be made */

    public RequestCallback successCallback;                     /*!< Function called when server responded with a status code 2XX (success) */
    public RequestCallback failureCallback;                     /*!< Any other status code than 2XX will trigger this function (failure) */
    public Hashtable failureCallbackArgs;                       /*!< This hashtable will be passed along to the 'successCallback' function as a mean to provide it with arguments */
    public Hashtable successCallbackArgs;                       /*!< This hashtable will be passed along to the 'failureCallback' function as a mean to provide it with arguments */

    /** Returns a string representation of the request that is human readable
     * \return A string describing the request parameters
     */
    public override string ToString(){

        string result = "Request to url: " + url + " method: " + method.ToString () + "\nHeaders:\n";
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in headers){
            result += kvp.Key + " -> " + kvp.Value + "\n";
        }
        result += "Params :\n";
        result += "resendOnFailure: " + resendOnFailure + "\n";
        result += "resendOnTimeout: " + resendOnTimeout + "\n";
        result += "askBeforeResending: " + askBeforeResending + "\n";
        result += "timeout: " + timeout + "\n";
        result += "maxAttempts: " + maxAttempts + "\n";
        result += "isInBackground: " + isInBackground + "\n";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: my best guess is that's because you are using fields instead of properties.

Comment: I said it used to be a struct, then I changed it to a class. And for the string, sorry I typed it instead of copying and made a mistake at this point

Comment: when I execute this code, I get `false` for `isInBackground`  (after changing it to bool), are you sure your logging is correct?

Comment: @GeoffreyHug My apologies, I misread.  That said, this code STILL will not compile as currently written.

Comment: @musefan That is not true; the params are optional when using an object initializer.

Comment: @GeoffreyHug You need to show a complete program that reproduces the problem you describe.  Your program not only doesn't compile, but doesn't reproduce the problem you claim it has.

Comment: I corrected it this should compile

Comment: @Servy: Ah, yes. Just tested. I also tested the full OP code (with the `bool`) and it works fine. `isInBackground` is false as expected.

Comment: @GeoffreyHug: Can you show full code to replicate, including how it is logged? I just tested it and it works fine. You are either reseting it somewhere else, or you are logging in a weird place (i.e. before it is changed)

Comment: Added full code, but I'm pretty sur nothing happens between creation of the object and the first log

Comment: I still can't see anything wrong in the code that would cause it. Have you tried commenting out the `isInBackground` field and see if the app break due to references in places you are not expecting them to be? I would also try commenting out everything else is that class and just leave `isInBackground` to see if that helps

Comment: So I'm working on Unity and I created a new Test scene with nothing in it, recreated the class and one that creates the object and logs, I posted the test code in edit. Still same result.

Comment: Here they say that it's a monodevelop problem : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/59530/microsoft-vs-mono-c-compiler-initialisation-differ.html#answer-59539

Answer (score 0):

This code fails in Unity because they use Mono. The bug is found only in using Mono and has nothing to do with C# language as Spoke44 pointed, the solution is to use properties :

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/59530/microsoft-vs-mono-c-compiler-initialisation-differ.html#answer-59539